# QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread. (Multithreading pyqt5)

Tags: multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to edit the text in 'QTextEdit' but I got the error which is in the title above. I know that I shouldn't edit the widgets in the main app from another thread and I searched for some answers, But I didn't get the full answer that I want

This is a sample that produce the same error that I have

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys
import time
import threading

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.move(50, 220)
        self.resize(500, 500)

        self.text_edit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.text_edit.resize(200, 200)
        
        self.btn = QPushButton('start', self)
        self.btn.move(10, 250)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda x : self.thread_creator(self.test))

        self.btn2 = QPushButton('print', self)
        self.btn2.move(10, 290)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(lambda x : print('dad'))


    def test(self):

        for i in range(99):
            self.text_edit.setText(f'dad {i}')
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def thread_creator(self, function):

        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=function)
        self.thread.start() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you explain what is your final purpose? There are be various ways to implement threading with Qt, and right now your function does practically nothing: for what we know, you could not even need a thread. In any case, 99% of the times the threading is achieved through QThread and custom signals.

Comment: I just want to set a text within the qtexteidt that has a length of 10000 and this takes a lot of time so I use threading to create a process so the gui doens't freeze, and this will allow me to edit another qtextedit or a qlable if I want

Comment: I Tried to use signals but I didn't manage to get what I want

Comment: Setting a text of 10000 characters shouldn't take that long: the operation is quite immediate on my 10-year old computer. And, in any case, using threading won't change anything, as the (possible, but still somehow strange) slow speed is caused by an UI element, and since that can only happen in the main thread, it would be completely pointless anyway.

Comment: thanks for your replay. I will try to find another solution to reduce lag